# Flutter : the release apk doesn't load the data from api

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, release

I was using release apk and it was work fine and I was added this permission in the manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifast>
```

this is an example for my api call

```
 Future<Branches> getBranches() async {
  // Reusable.showLoading(context);
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(baseUrl + "branches"),
  );
  //Reusable.dismissLoading();
  return new Branches.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}

class Branches {
  List<Datum> data;

  Branches({this.data});

  Branches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['posts'] != null) {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      data = new List<Datum>();
      json['posts'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Datum.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Datum {
  String id;
  String name;
  String img;

  Datum({this.id, this.name, this.img});

  Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
  }
```

and the url support https

But now, suddenly and incomprehensibly it is no longer working
There is anything can cause this !!!

Comment: Hi there. Question is incomplete. Add more details. How are you calling your api ? Post more code samples;

Comment: the problem not in api , the api was work in release mode but now it doesn't was no reasons or errors

Comment: Could you provide your api url ? This mostly happens due to `clearTextTraffic`. Does your api support `https` ?

Comment: yes , it supports it : https://example.com/api/login

Comment: Try handling error case and try showing error on screen in a toast or something. You would need to post something related to the error for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I want to share that but I haven't an error in console

Comment: In that case, try putting `print` and handle the error cases. that might explain something.

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_GrowableList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I get this error

Comment: Aaah, see. Now we have something. Post you full code where you are using these things.

Comment: I did it now , please check it

Comment: Share your url, this is something to do with the data you are getting

Comment: thanks for your help i found that my api list return with empty list so that i got this problem